# Convert Binary to PNG in PHP?

Tags: php, image, feed

I am receiving a file from a feed, it is in binary format.

this code will display the image on the screen

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
print $image;
```

However I have tried a number of different ways of saving the .png such as imagepng() but nothing seems to work

The start of the binary feed is quite long but the start is...

```
‰PNG  IHDR,,ö"€IDATxÚì½w”×uîÉ²¯,K²_²×{Ë^~ÿ½ûîµ˜)‹T°¨kI¤ˆ<9çäLd$E*X™ T@™ÈÌ`òôL§ÊÕÕ©r>oŸsº{¢|%‚âëZß*zª{zºëWßÞ'ì3U¶ÊVÙ®ë6§òT¶ÊV°²U¶ „•­²U¶ „•­²U ¬l•­²U ¬l•­ae«l•­á»nÿ@U¶ÊVð¹Ù[ÂÊVðOŽYÙÍ÷ý ¸W ß¾*—Te«@ø{¨Þd+'°´áÿéòÃ€Ê|Ð›
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: "Convert Binary to PNG " does not make sense. PNG is binary. The bytesyou are getting is no more no less than a PNG, you just need to save that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `imagecreatefromstring()` to get an image resource, then you can save it using `imagepng()`.

Comment: imagepng(imagecreatefromstring($image),$imagename.'.png');

Answer (score 0):

assuming that the browser shows the image in the first example, just tweak it to become a file download :

```
<?php
  header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
  header('Content-Type: image/png');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Image.png');
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Expires: 0');
  header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
  header('Pragma: public');
  header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($image));
  ob_clean();  // Just in case you have output buffers enabled
  flush();
  print $image;
```

Comment: Great, thats a nice bit of code, but my only problem is that I need the file saving to disk as its going to be run through a cron job Sorry I should have said.

Comment: have you tried simply saving the string to a file called 'image.png'? (don't know if it will actually work)